# Issue Tracking mouse movement in Iframe

Tags: javascript

**Details :-**

In Our Project, we need to implement a functionality where we need to logout the user if he/she is inactive for 5 minutes. We need to consider user as inactive if he/she has not moved mouse for 5 mins.

We are able to achieve this in all normal pages but facing difficulties to implement in one page where we have an iframe in a page and that iframe plays videos and other swf, mp4 files. Also inside an iframe, there is another frame which acts as a wrapper for the content.

In above page, we are not able to track mouse movement and hence not able to detect whether user is active or not.

After lots of research, we have implemented code which works fine if we run through browser console but doesn't work when I keep this on page.

Has someone worked on similar functionality or know anything related to this? It would be great if someone can help me for this functionality.

> Note :- Also there are click in Iframes

Answer (score 0):

The iframe's source is technically speaking its own document (documentception?). The trick is to listen to the mouse events inside this document. Though I don't if this is allowed by the same origin policy, you could always give it a try.

Using plain JS:

```
var iframeDocument = document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument;

iframeDocument.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
});
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('iframe').contents().mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
```

You could go even further by dispatching all events made inside the iframe's document to the parent document. This gives you the advantage to use just one listener for all events, whether they come from inside the `<iframe>` or not.